# A zero \parskip and an unusual \paragraph result in overlapping paragraphs

Tags: spacing, sectioning, indentation, sections-paragraphs

I'm trying to debug a class provided by some journal.  From times to times, the text appears completely garbled, or does not appear at all (I believe it is printed *somewhere* but probably out of the page).  This class is a complete (and useless) reimplementation of `article`, but I think I narrowed down the problem.

Consider the following document:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{article}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \makeatletter
 \renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}
                               {4}{\z@}{12pt \@plus -3pt}{-.5em}
                               {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
 \parskip\z@
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}
 \lipsum[1-3]
 \paragraph{New Par} \footnote{Oh}\lipsum[1-2]
 \end{document}
```

While I believe that the `\paragraph` definition is inoffensive it seems
that, in combination with the `\parskip\z@`, the results get wrong:

[image]

**Question:** What fix should I give to the editor?  Don't set `\parskip` to
  zero?  Is that really the problem?  Is the problem in the definition of
  \paragraph?

Comment: The garbled part is the footnote. Remove the `\textheight46.1c` and it looks normal again.

Comment: OT: `\p@` is defined as `1pt`. Instead of `0\p@` you can use `\z@`, which is defined as `0pt`.

Comment: @percusse: Thanks for your input.  However, I believe I should be able to use the \textheight I want without having the text garbled.  This is just a fine tuning to trigger the (un)desired result, and I think it is legit to expect it to work.  @Aditya:  Right, thanks.  I think they just copied the line from `article`, which uses the even stranger `0\p@ \@plus \p@`.

Comment: You should give a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so people can test.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: I managed to reduce the WE so that it is close to M.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is with the definition of `\paragraph`: the fourth argument ("beforeskip") contains a negative `plus` component, which it shouldn't. Changing this to `12pt \@plus 3pt` fixes it.

A negative stretch (or shrink) is hardly ever useful, except for [certain cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46980/7674).

Usually, I would leave it at that – but because I suspect that there is a reason to why this negative stretch is there (and because you've asked for it ...), it might be worthwhile to delve into the intricacies of `\@startsection`:

According to [source2e](http://www.tex.ac.uk/CTAN/macros/latex/doc/source2e.pdf), the "beforeskip" argument is to specify the following:

> Absolute value = skip to leave above the heading. If negative, then paragraph indent of text following heading is suppressed.

Now, if `latex` encounters a negative value (of the first part: e.g., `-12pt`), it will (1) reverse the sign of the skip (which means reversing the sign of all components of this skip: its natural width, stretch and shrink), and (2) set the paragraph indentation switch to false. So that, for example, `-12pt \@plus -3pt \@minus -3pt` would actually mean: beforeskip of `12pt \@plus 3pt \@minus 3pt` and "no indentation of the next paragraph". Since negative stretch or shrink components usually don't make much sense (see above), *all* components should be either positive or negative, but not mixed.

The fifth argument ("afterskip") specifies:

> if positive, then skip to leave below heading, else negative of skip to leave to right of run-in heading.

In your definition of `\paragraph`, the fifth argument is negative, signalling that it should be a run-in heading, and not start a new paragraph. Therefore, it actually does not matter whether "beforeskip" is positive or negative, as text following a run-in heading is of course never indented.

Comment: Thanks Robert!  Would you mind adding a reference for your assertion to the effect that *all* components have to be negative if one is?  Or explain how the different components behave?  I thought that `\@plus` and `\@minus` were only arithmetics (as their names suggest), so maybe you can explain how these work too?  Thanks!

Comment: In addition, your "of course" sentence means that any value sign would have the same result, can you explain why?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Michaël See my updated answer.

Comment: That's very kind of you, thanks.  I changed the name of the question to better reflect the problematic at hand.